# getting array out of bounds exception in java

Tags: java

hey guys i am not sure how to fix the code below as i get an area out of bounds exception every time i run it any help would be greatly appreciated to fix this thx.

```
int numberStudents = numberOfStudents();  
    System.out.println("");
    int[] gradeOfStudent = gradeOfStudents(numberStudents);
```

method is below

```
public static int[] gradeOfStudents(int numberStudents) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int[] grades = new int [numberStudents];
    String[] name = new String[numberStudents];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberStudents;) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numberStudents; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the " + (i + 1) + " student: ");
        name[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " student's grade: " );
        grades[i] = input.nextInt();              
        }
    } 
    return grades;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be sure to add the whole exception stacktrace along with your question.

Comment: You're increment `i` in a loop that is conditioned on `j`, so that will **loop forever**. --- *Hint:* Get rid of the `j` loop, you should only have a regular `i` loop.

Comment: Time to learn about the debugger, breakpoints and stepping through code ... :)

Comment: I think you need to learn about how `for` loop works. I suggest you read [For loop in Java with example - BeginnersBook](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/for-loop-in-java-with-example/) to understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a second loop inside your gradeOfStudents(int) method:

```
for(int j = 0; j < numberStudents; i++ ) {
```

As you can see, the loop variable is 'j' but it updates 'i' after every cycle - thus the i < numberStudents check in the first loop is no longer called for every 'i' -> it can be out of bounds.

You also don't seem to be using 'j' for anything, that whole loop might be redundant.

Comment: ah ok i see now that makes sense. i got rid of that loop and it works now thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `gradeOfStudents()` method. You have 2 `for` loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberStudents;) {
    for(int j = 0; j < numberStudents; i++ ) {
```

Your first loop runs `numberOfStudents` times, the second loop also runs `numberOfStudents` times.

The real problem here is, that you do `i++` for each of those iterations. So you increase `i` to `numberOfStudents * 2`. But your arrays are only of size `numberOfStudents`.

There is actually no point in the second loop, as you don't need and apparently also don't use `j`. One loop is enough for this task. The fixed snippet would look like this:

```
public static int[] gradeOfStudents(int numberStudents) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int[] grades = new int [numberStudents];
    String[] name = new String[numberStudents];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the " + (i + 1) + " student: ");
        name[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " student's grade: " );
        grades[i] = input.nextInt();              
    }
    return grades;
}
```

But with this approach, you can see that you actually discard the `name` array completely. I don't think you want that.

So a more object-oriented approach would be, to create a class `Student`, which then holds the attributes `grade` and `name`.

So something like this:

```
class Student {

    private int grade;
    private String name;

    public Student(int grade, String name) {
        this.grade = grade;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    // then provide getters and setters for the attributes

}
```

And then create and store a `new Student(grade, name)` for each of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your j for loop and add the i++ (increment i) to your first for loop

```
public static int[] gradeOfStudents(int numberStudents) {
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int[] grades = new int [numberStudents];
String[] name = new String[numberStudents];
for(int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the " + (i + 1) + " student: ");
    name[i] = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " student's grade: " );
    grades[i] = input.nextInt();              
} 
return grades;
```

}